# QT Designer добавление динамического свойства типа Enum для кастомного виджета

Tags: qt, qt-designer

Создал пользователський виджет файл пикера (НЕ ПЛАГИН), для него завел режим Mode(входной/выходной). На основной форме в дизайнере я использую "преобразовывать в.." (FilePicker)

```
class FilePicker : public QWidget{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(Mode     mode        READ getMode        WRITE setMode)
   Q_PROPERTY(QString  extension   READ getExtension   WRITE setExtension)
   Q_ENUMS(Mode)
   public:
      explicit FilePicker(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
      ~FilePicker();
     enum class Mode{
        In  = QFileDialog::AcceptMode::AcceptOpen,
        Out = QFileDialog::AcceptMode::AcceptSave
     };
     void setMode(const Mode val);
     Mode getMode() const;

     void setExtension(const QString& ext);
     QString getExtension() const;
 signals:
     void changed(const QString& path);
 private:
    Ui::FilePicker *ui;
    QFileDialog* _dialog;
 private slots:
    void showDialog();
    void fileSelected();
};
```

Для добавления свойств использую кнопку "Добавить динамическое свойство"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Свойство для задания расширения extension пробросить удается, так как это строка, а для свойства "mode" в списке типов нельзя выбрать enum . Можно переделать на строки или int, но может как-то можно enum пробросить?

Qt Creator 4.7 qt 5.1